# Send email when date in column will be in 180 days workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I´m new in SharePoint, it will be great if you can help me.

**I need to create workflow for this situation:**

I have list with my customers. There is a column "End of contract" and I would like to set up workflow for sending emails 180 before expiration of contranct.

Could you help me with that, please?

Thank you so much for your answers

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Something has to trigger a workflow unless you go down the route of Powershell and scheduling a script to run.

However, if it's based on a list, you can enable retention on that list. For example, if you create an item in a list and enable retention for say 2 days after that's created to kick off a workflow, that's possible

The other thing that you can do is that when an item is added to a list/library, you can pause a workflow for a specified amount of time, then run the same

Comment: +1 for mentioning that there needs to be a trigger. Old data needs something that kicks this workflow of. You can run it on item updated, but that wont catch any old data. And you can use the delay option